# Kotlin Android Studio - "If" is not executing in correct condition

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

I am trying to make a simple Kotlin program of sign in page. The concept here was that this page will get the intent extras coming from the register page and use them to verify if the user logged in with the same registered username and password which would then bring the user to the main page of the app. The problem is that when the user *actually does* put the correct input, the intent won't execute (or rather the if gate).

At first I thought that the nullsafe strings were the problem when I took the intent data from the register page and so I converted the variable into a string.

But it was still no bueno so I'm not sure what is the wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the `username` and `userPass` at creation of the screen so they will be always empty String. Try moving them to inside the listener so they actually will be read out when you click the button. Like

```
val intent = intent
val registeredUsername = intent.getStringExtra("RegisteredUsername").toString()
val registeredPassword = intent.getStringExtra("RegisteredPassword").toString()

signInbtn.setOnClickListener{
    val username = usernameInput.text.toString()
    val userPass = passwordInput.text.toString()

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "username is: $registeredUsername", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "password is: $registeredPassword", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    if ((username == registeredUsername) && (userPass == registeredPassword))
    {
        val moveMainPage = Intent(this@SignIn, MainPage::class.java)
        startActivity(moveMainPage)
    }
    else
    {
        invalideUserText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        invalidPassword.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

}
```

Comment: Life saver bro! Didn't even know that there were differences between putting them outside of the listener!

Comment: @DepletedMoney you're creating a variable (e.g. `username`) and assigning it a value by reading the *current state* of a text field, so *when* you do that is important! It's a simple "read value, store value" operation so it won't update as that text field updates, so you basically have to read that value just before you decide what to do with it. By putting it in the click listener, you only look at the contents and decide what to do *when the button is clicked*. By creating those variables outside the click listener, you're basically reading and assigning the values at setup instead